# Oracle Data Integrator Scalar Function Usage

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I have a scalar function in my source database schema which I am using it to get balance of the specified account.

```
NVL(MYGL.F_GET_LAST_ACC_BALANCE(ACCOUNTS.ACC_NO, TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1),0)
```

In ODI mapping I would like to use this function to get balance of the accounts and then load them into my DWH DB.

I am using IKM Oracle Insert with DbLink.

I tried to use EXPRESSION inside mapping however that didn't give me the result because ODI tries to execute `MYGL.F_GET_LAST_ACC_BALANCE` on `DWH` side not on the source side. `MYGL.F_GET_LAST_ACC_BALANCE` is defined in Source DB.

This is the generated query

```
INSERT 
  /*+  APPEND PARALLEL  */ 
  INTO DWH.FACT_ACCOUNTS
  (
    REPORT_DATE ,
    ACC_NO ,
    ACC_PROD_CODE ,
    REAL_BALANCE ,
    LAST_BALANCE 
  ) 
SELECT 
  TRUNC(SYSDATE) ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_NO ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_PROD_CODE ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_BALANCE ,
  (NVL(MYGL.F_GET_LAST_ACC_BALANCE(ACCOUNTS.ACC_NO, TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1),0))  
FROM 
  <schema>.<table>@<dblink_to_source> ACCOUNTS
```

What it needs to be

```
INSERT 
  /*+  APPEND PARALLEL  */ 
  INTO DWH.FACT_ACCOUNTS
  (
    REPORT_DATE ,
    ACC_NO ,
    ACC_PROD_CODE ,
    REAL_BALANCE ,
    LAST_BALANCE 
  ) 
SELECT 
  TRUNC(SYSDATE) ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_NO ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_PROD_CODE ,
  ACCOUNTS.ACC_BALANCE ,
  (NVL(MYGL.F_GET_LAST_ACC_BALANCE@<dblink_to_source>(ACCOUNTS.ACC_NO, TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1),0))  
FROM 
  <schema>.<table>@<dblink_to_source> ACCOUNTS
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need it's too custom for using a predefined Oracle KM.

I think that a solution it's to use another IKM, that it's not using DBLINK, instead it's using a JDBC connection (connect directly to source, through the jdbc defined in the Physical schema).

In this way, your code will be executed directly on the source and the function will be recognized.

Comment: is there specific IKM that you can advice? or is it needed to be written or modified by myself?

Comment: What technology do you have for source and for target?

Comment: they are both on Oracle Database 11.2.0.4

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, try: IKM Oracle Insert , IKM Oracle Load , IKM SQL Insert or IKM Oracle Load